# How to create a search scope for content type in a sub site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, search-scope

I have parent site i.e sharepoint.microsoft.com

& a sub site sharepoint.microsoft.com/child/

Now a content type  named "Problem" in created in sub site.

I would like to add this content type in the search scope by adding the rule as "ContentType = Problem" in scopes but its not pointing to the content type in sub site..

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell to add a rule to a scope by using [New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScopeRule](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608132.aspx) . Technet has some nice examples.